# Laravel 8 with Inertia is not finding a view component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I'm building a platform in laravel 8 and implemented inertia on it. I have a problem previewing a component.
I created everything as instructed in the inertia documentation. Everything was working until I needed to add code splitting to the code.
I added a type="module" to packet.json and changed the name of the laravel mix to webpack.mix.cjs and compiled it without errors, but it doesn't find my modules.

My component Home.vue:

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

My route calling the component:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Home');
});
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './Home' at app.js:19469

Line 19469:
function webpackAsyncContext(req) {
    if(!__webpack_require__.o(map, req)) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
            e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
            throw e;
        });
    }

    var ids = map[req], id = ids[0];
    return __webpack_require__.e(ids[1]).then(() => {
        return __webpack_require__(id);
    });
}
```

Laravel mix:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js' , 'public/js');

mix.vue();
```

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'

InertiaProgress.init()

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => import('./Pages/' + name),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        new Vue({
            render: h => h(App, props),
        }).$mount(el)
    },
})
```

Solutions already tried without success:

- Clear browser cache.
- Clear laravel cache.
- I ran npm run dev several times to ensure.

Comment: Do you have Home.vue under resources/js/Pages?